# How can I make footer like this?

Tags: html, css

This is a footer that I have to create a footer.
But I don't know how to make the circle stay at half on top footer like this

[image: footer]

Now I can create a footer like this but still has a problem

[image: footer that I can't handle with TT]

and this is my code right now

```css
.Footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #ffde6a;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Circle {
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.input-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer">
  <div class="Circle">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#262626" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M3 22H21C21 17.5817 16.9706 14 12 14C7.02944 14 3 17.5817 3 22Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                        <path d="M16.5 6.5C16.5 8.98528 14.4853 11 12 11C9.51472 11 7.5 8.98528 7.5 6.5C7.5 4.01472 9.51472 2 12 2C14.4853 2 16.5 4.01472 16.5 6.5Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"/>
                    </svg>
    </div>
    Profile
  </div>
```

If anyone knows how to create footer like the first pic please help me TT.
I will really really appreciate Hope every one has a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Profile</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Footer">
        <div class="Circle">
            <div class="input-icon">
                <svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#262626" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M3 22H21C21 17.5817 16.9706 14 12 14C7.02944 14 3 17.5817 3 22Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                        <path d="M16.5 6.5C16.5 8.98528 14.4853 11 12 11C9.51472 11 7.5 8.98528 7.5 6.5C7.5 4.01472 9.51472 2 12 2C14.4853 2 16.5 4.01472 16.5 6.5Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"/>
                    </svg>
            </div>
            Profile
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
}

.Footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #fadf7c;
  font-family: verdana;
}

.Circle {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fadf7c;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Hope this helps<3[image: screenshot:]

Answer (score 1):

The [translateY() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) repositions an element vertically on the 2D plane.

```css
.Footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #ffde6a;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Circle {
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer">
  <div class="Circle">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#262626" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M3 22H21C21 17.5817 16.9706 14 12 14C7.02944 14 3 17.5817 3 22Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        <path d="M16.5 6.5C16.5 8.98528 14.4853 11 12 11C9.51472 11 7.5 8.98528 7.5 6.5C7.5 4.01472 9.51472 2 12 2C14.4853 2 16.5 4.01472 16.5 6.5Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    Profile
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: #ffde6a;
    color: #262626;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.Circle {
    height: 66px;
    width: 66px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #ffde6a;
    margin-top: -66px;
}

.input-icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <footer class="Footer">
      <div class="Circle">
        <div class="input-icon">
          <svg
            width="36"
            height="36"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="#262626"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M3 22H21C21 17.5817 16.9706 14 12 14C7.02944 14 3 17.5817 3 22Z"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1.5"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
            />
            <path
              d="M16.5 6.5C16.5 8.98528 14.4853 11 12 11C9.51472 11 7.5 8.98528 7.5 6.5C7.5 4.01472 9.51472 2 12 2C14.4853 2 16.5 4.01472 16.5 6.5Z"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1.5"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      Profile
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since you are using a fixed amout of pixels for the circle, you can give the circle the same amount of pixels as a negative margin-top. In this case     margin-top: -66px;. You should also use the html footer element instead of a div, for best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this:

```css
.Footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: #ffde6a;
    color: #262626;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .Circle {
    height: 66px;
    width: 66px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
    background-color: #ffde6a;
  }
  
  .input-icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .profile-text{
    font-size: inherit;
  }
  
  .input-icon,
  .profile-text{
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="Footer">
  <div class="Circle">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#262626" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M3 22H21C21 17.5817 16.9706 14 12 14C7.02944 14 3 17.5817 3 22Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        <path d="M16.5 6.5C16.5 8.98528 14.4853 11 12 11C9.51472 11 7.5 8.98528 7.5 6.5C7.5 4.01472 9.51472 2 12 2C14.4853 2 16.5 4.01472 16.5 6.5Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <h1 class="profile-text">
      Profile
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course you can do it your own way, but this is how I would do it without changing too much of your code.

NOTE: When the footer position is fixed, it was always stay at the bottom of your screen, not document. Meaning that when you scroll, it will regardless stay at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #ffde6a;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ffde6a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-30%);
  border: 1.5rem solid #ffde6a;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Footer">
    <div class="Circle">
      <div class="input-icon">
        <svg width="70" height="70" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#262626" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M3 22H21C21 17.5817 16.9706 14 12 14C7.02944 14 3 17.5817 3 22Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke-linejoin="round" />
          <path
            d="M16.5 6.5C16.5 8.98528 14.4853 11 12 11C9.51472 11 7.5 8.98528 7.5 6.5C7.5 4.01472 9.51472 2 12 2C14.4853 2 16.5 4.01472 16.5 6.5Z"
            stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      Profile
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <!--
  This script places a badge on your repl's full-browser view back to your repl's cover
  page. Try various colors for the theme: dark, light, red, orange, yellow, lime, green,
  teal, blue, blurple, magenta, pink!
  -->
    <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge-v2.js" theme="dark" position="bottom-right"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7MHc.png)

you can also see the code and output in replit: https://replit.com/@hariomchouhan/QuestionableHeartfeltGames#index.html